# Measurement Error in Dynamic Linear Model

Tags: measurement-error, dlm

I have fitted a `dlm` model as follow:

```
    buildFun <- function(x) {dlmModReg(rev(X), addInt = TRUE, dV = exp(x[1]), dW = exp(x[2:3]))}
    fit <- dlmMLE(rev(Y), parm = c(10,0.01,0.01), buildFun)
    dlmReg <- buildFun(fit$par)
RegFilt <- dlmFilter(rev(Y), dlmReg)
e<-rev(RegFilt$y[2:length(RegFilt$y)]-RegFilt$f[2:length(RegFilt$f)])
```

`sd(e)` not equals to `sqrt(V(dlmReg))`??